Widgets not load data from cache in ios
I am using "home_widget" flutter package to add home widget option to my flutter application.
I saved data from my flutter code to cache by "shared_prefences".
this is my swift code to show a widget like this
but I can not see preview of widgets and after adding it to home screen list not showed seems data not loaded, seems the home widget is not updated , please see my code and help me
private let widgetGroupId = "group.myWidgetGroup"
let logger = OSLog(subsystem: "com.kkkk.widget", category: 
"WidgetLogging")// Provider to handle the timeline for widget entries
struct Provider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
let data = UserDefaults(suiteName: widgetGroupId)

func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {

//fake data
let fakeItems = [
FeedItem(title: "First Item", descriptions: "Description for first item",
dateTime: "2024-04-15 12:00:00", avatar: nil, event: nil, fromUserName: "Alice",
addedByNickName: "Alice", toName: "Bob", clientName: "Client A", clientId: "1",
itemList: [], type: "Update", staffName: "Staff A", value: 100.0),
FeedItem(title: "Second Item", descriptions: "Description for second item",
dateTime: "2024-04-15 12:05:00", avatar: nil, event: nil, fromUserName: "Charlie",
addedByNickName: "Charlie", toName: "Dana", clientName: "Client B", clientId: "2",
itemList: [], type: "Review", staffName: "Staff B", value: 200.0)
]
   let feedData = FeedData(header: "Updated Header", items: fakeItems, range: "This 
  Month", currency: "USD", key: "testKey")
   return SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent(), feedItems: 
 feedData)
 }


  func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async 
   -> SimpleEntry {
   

// loadFeedItems load data from cache
      if let feedData = loadFeedItems() {
            print("swift to load feed items.")
                let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration: configuration, 
     feedItems: feedData)
                return entry
            } else {
                print("swift Failed to load feed items.")
                return SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration: configuration, 
   feedItems: FeedData(header: "", items: [], range: "", currency: "", key: ""))
            }
}




func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> 
     Timeline<SimpleEntry> {
       guard let feedData = loadFeedItems() else {
                   print("Failed to load feed items.")
                   let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration: configuration , 
    feedItems: FeedData(header: "", items: [], range: "", currency: "", key: ""))
                   let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
                   return timeline
                   
               }
               let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration: configuration , 
     feedItems: feedData)
               let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
               return timeline
    }

// load data from cache
 func loadFeedItems() -> FeedData? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    guard let jsonString = data?.string(forKey: "feed_large_all_json"),
          let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        print("Error: Cannot create Data from jsonString")
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(FeedData.self, from: jsonData)
        return decodedData
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
  }
  }


struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
 let date: Date
 let configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent
  let feedItems: FeedData
 }

 // Main view for the widget entry
struct FeedAllHomeWidgetEntryView: View {
 var entry: SimpleEntry

 var body: some View {
    WidgetMainView(data: entry.feedItems)
 }
}

// Widget definition
struct feed_all_home_widget: Widget {
let kind: String = "feed_all_home_widget"

var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationAppIntent.self, provider: 
   Provider()) { entry in
        FeedAllHomeWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("Feed Home Widget")
    .supportedFamilies([.systemLarge])
 }
}

 extension ConfigurationAppIntent {
fileprivate static var smiley: ConfigurationAppIntent {
    let intent = ConfigurationAppIntent()
    intent.favoriteEmoji = ""
    return intent
 }
 }
 // Widget preview for development
 struct FeedAllHomeWidgetPreview: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    FeedAllHomeWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration:.smiley, 
  feedItems: FeedDataProvider.data))
        .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemLarge))
 }
 }

// Main view that builds the UI for the widget
 struct WidgetMainView: View {
 var data: FeedData

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            // Header with guaranteed space
            HeaderView(title: "Title", range: "Sub title")
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.2) // Allocates 20% of the 
     total height to the header

            // List of items with the remaining space
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                ForEach(data.items.prefix(3), id: \.identifier) { item in
               FeedItemView(item: item,currency:data.currency)

                }
            }

            // Uses 80% of the total height for the list
        }
    }

    .background(Color.white)
    .frame( alignment: .top) // Ensures the content is aligned to the top
 }
 }

// Header view component and header loaded
struct HeaderView: View {
var title: String
var range: String

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(title).font(.system(size: 17)).bold()
        Text(range).font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(.gray)
    }

    .background(Color.white)
}
}

// Individual feed item view component
struct FeedItemView: View {
var item: FeedItem
var currency: String

var body: some View {
 GeometryReader { geometry in
     HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 5) {
       Rectangle()
                       .fill(generateColorFromText("\(item.clientName)"))
                       .frame(width: 3, height: geometry.size.height)
                       .cornerRadius(1.5)
                       .padding(.trailing, 5)

         VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                      if !item.title.isEmpty {
                                    Text(item.title).bold()
                                }
                                if !item.type.isEmpty {
                                    Text("Action : \(item.type)").bold()
                                }
                                if !item.clientName.isEmpty {
                                    Text("Client Name: \(item.clientName)").bold()
                                }
                                if !item.staffName.isEmpty {
                                    Text("Staff Name: \(item.staffName)").bold()
                                }
                                if !item.fromUserName.isEmpty && !item.toName.isEmpty 
     {
                                    Text("From : \(item.fromUserName) to : \. 
                                        (item.toName)").bold()
                                }
                                if !item.addedByNickName.isEmpty {
                                    Text("Added by : \(item.addedByNickName)").bold()
                                }

                                    Text("Value: \(currency) \(item.value)").bold()

                                if !item.descriptions.isEmpty {
                                    Text(item.descriptions).lineLimit(3)
                                }
                                if !item.dateTime.isEmpty {
                                     if let formattedDate = 
                           convertDateFormat(item.dateTime) {
                                    Text("\ 
                          (formattedDate)").font(.caption).foregroundColor(.gray)

                                    }
                                }
         }
         .font(.system(size: 12))
     }
   }
  // Adjust this height as necessary
 .padding(.vertical, 3)
 .widgetURL(URL(string: "homeWidgetExample://message? 
    message=feed_larg_allkey&homeWidget"))


    }

func generateColorFromText(_ text: String) -> Color {
var hash = 0
for char in text.unicodeScalars {
    hash = Int(char.value) + ((hash << 5) - hash)
}

// Ensuring the hash is positive before taking modulo operation
let positiveHash = abs(hash)
let hue = CGFloat(positiveHash % 360) / 360  // Normalize hue to be a value between 0 
  and 1
let saturation: CGFloat = 0.5
let brightness: CGFloat = 0.6
let color = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 
  1.0)
return Color(color)
 }

 func convertDateFormat(_ input: String) -> String? {
 // Create a DateFormatter for the original format
 let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
 inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 inputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // Set locale to handle 24- 
  hour time
 inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // Optional: Adjust this for 
  your timezone

 // Convert the input string to a Date object
 guard let date = inputFormatter.date(from: input) else {
     print("Invalid date format")
     return nil
 }

 // Create a DateFormatter for the output format
 let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
 outputFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
 outputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 outputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // Optional: Adjust this for 
  your timezone

 // Convert the Date object to the output format string
 return outputFormatter.string(from: date)
 }

 }

 // Dummy data provider for previews and tests
 struct FeedDataProvider {
static let data: FeedData = FeedData(header: "", items: [], range: "", currency: "", 
   key: "")
   }

//my model
struct FeedData: Codable {
var header: String
var items: [FeedItem]
var range: String
var currency: String
var key: String
}

struct FeedItem: Codable {
var title: String
var descriptions: String
var dateTime: String
var avatar: String?
var event: String?
var fromUserName: String
var addedByNickName: String
var toName: String
var clientName: String
var clientId: String
var itemList: [String]
var type: String
var staffName: String
var value: Double

// Computed identifier
    var identifier: String {
        "\(dateTime)-\(title)- \(clientId)"
    }
 }

